# SQL Server Count Function

Tags: sql-server

Can Any One Tell me how range if `Count(*)` in `SQL` Server i.e How much rows it count Return.
when to use `big_count()` in `SQL Server`

Thank u 
Dinesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`COUNT` returns an INTEGER so max value is: 2,147,483,647
`COUNT_BIG` returns a BIGINT so max value is: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

[INT/BIGINT datatype reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)